# How to get a DOM element by id in Javascript code embedded in PHP when using tpl (Smarty)?

Tags: php, dom, upload, smarty, jquery-ui-resizable

Objective: To be able to load a user selected image file in a resizeable div to allow resizing of image before submitting (using a jQuery resizable plugin).

1) The layout of the view is defined in upload_myimage.tpl.html (snippet shown below).

2) It is initialized to show an arbitrary image in a div which is set to "resizeable". The image displays and the resizing works.

3) After choosing an image file and clicking on "Upload File" (a button in an HTML Form), the PHP function update_mypicture() (snippet shown below) is called to replace the aforementioned image. Error on line 24 of upload.php: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of null. img for some reason is returned as null. Any ideas why?

-- snippet of tpl code --

```
<div id ="box">
    <img src="/image/logo.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" id="image"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#box").resizable(); 
</script>
```

-- snippet of php code --

```
<?php
  if($_POST['submitScaleName'] == "Submit") {
  ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function scale_mypicture(pic){
            var img = parent.document.getElementById("image");      // img is returned as null
             img.setAttribute("src", pic);
             var memeFilename = parent.document.getElementById("memeFilename");
             memeFilename.value = "<?php echo $_FILES['file']["name"]; ?>";
        }
        parent.document.getElementById("img_filename").value = "";
        scale_mypicture("<?php echo '/image/'.$_FILES['file']["name"]; ?>");
        </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Where do you call what code? Could you please explain the control flow of your application?